# Rent available cars from rentals table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have my table with rentals

```
id| user_id| car_id | starting_date | ending_date
```

and here is cars table

```
id | name
```

I don't know how to habndle the situation.. I have N cars, and I want to return only available cars for specific dates.

For example I want to rent a car on this period:
20.02.2018 - 23.02.2018

But I don't know how to check every case to see if a car is available in that period using Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method. I assume you already have `rentals` relationship defined:

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse('20.02.2018')->startOfDay();
$date2 = Carbon::parse('23.02.2018')->endOfDay();
$available = Car::whereDoesntHave('rentals', function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
    $q->whereBetween('starting_date', [$date1, $date2])
      ->orWhereBetween('ending_date', [$date1, $date2])
      ->orWhere(function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
          $q->where('starting_date', '<', $date1)
            ->where('ending_date', '>', $date2);
      });
})
->get();
```

If you don't have the relationship, define it in the `Car` model:

```
public function rentals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rental::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Alexey Mezenin. But here is a problem I guess. For example right now in rentals database exist a period 18.02.2018 - 25.02.2018. How can I handle this case because.. this dates are not between $date1 and $date2.

Comment: @Rince1934 added logic for this case too.

Comment: That's great! I guess now every case is provided.. or?

Comment: Yes, now all cases are covered.