# Laravel Relationship Not Working as Expected- Rental Car Search

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, relationship

I'm trying to make a rent-a-car website and I'm stuck at the search functionality.

The input will be a pick up date and drop off date and the result should be a list of cars that are available in that period.

This are my tables:

- Cars: id, name, category etc.
- Placement: id, client_name, client_second_name etc.
- Invoice: id (irrelevant), placement_id, car_id, pick_up_date, drop_off_date.

These are my relationships:

For `Car` model:

```
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}

public function placements()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Placement');
}
```

For `Placement` model:

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}

public function car()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Car');
}
```

For `Invoice` model:

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
}

public function placements()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Placement');
}
```

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794200/rent-available-cars-from-rentals-table) on this problem, but I don't really know how to apply that response:

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse('20.02.2018')->startOfDay();
$date2 = Carbon::parse('23.02.2018')->endOfDay();
$available = Car::whereDoesntHave('rentals', function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
    $q->whereBetween('starting_date', [$date1, $date2])
      ->orWhereBetween('ending_date', [$date1, $date2])
      ->orWhere(function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
          $q->where('starting_date', '<', $date1)
            ->where('ending_date', '>', $date2);
      });
})
->get();
```

If I try to run this: `$available = Car::doesntHave('placements')->get();`, just for test purpose, I get this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cars.placements_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cars` where not exists (select * from `placements` where `cars`.`placements_id` = `placements`.`id`))

Can you help me, please? If not with an exact response, maybe with an explanation?

Comment: Does `cars.placements_id` actually exist in your db?

Comment: No.In cars table are stored only the details about the car.In Placements table are stored only the details about the order and in the Invoice table are stored the links between them.A row in Invoice should be like this: car_id = 3, placement_id = 5, pick_up_date = 3.10.2018 and drop_off_date = 10.10.2018.So, 3 it's the foreign key to the car with the id 3 and 5 to the order with id 5.

Comment: Looks like you need to link your placement table to your car table in that case. I image you'd want to know the id of the car which has been placed.

Comment: Exactly.But i'd linked it.It's not ok?

Answer (score 0):

This message is basically saying that you don't have a `placements_id` in your car table:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cars.placements_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cars` where not exists (select * from `placements` where `cars`.`placements_id` = `placements`.`id`))
```

Lets look at the Cars Model:

```
public function placements(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Placement');
}
```

This is saying Cars belongs to Placements, which would result in a `cars.placements_id = placements.id` relationship.

The other way round would be

```
 public function placements(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Placement');
 }
```

This would result in a `cars.id = placements.cars_id` relationship.

It all depends on how you want your data structured.

EDIT

To meet your requirements you could approach the structure as follows (obviously you would add your own columns and data, but heres how it would essentially work):

Cars:

```
id | name
------------
1  | Fiesta
2  | Focus
```

Reservations:

```
id | cars_id | placements_id | date_from  | date_to
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      |  1           | 2018-10-16 | 2018-10-18
2  | 1      |  2           | 2018-10-19 | 2018-10-19
3  | 2      |  3           | 2018-10-19 | 2018-10-19
```

Placements

```
id | first_name | surname
--------------------------
1  | Jeff       | Hardy
2  | Matt       | Hardy 
3  | James      | Giraffe
```

You would have to add the reservations model whilst also changing some of the relationships in the other models, but with my explanation above i'm sure you can work that one out.

Comment: Ohh....I see.The relations should not be car-placements and other way.All relations should be car->invoice and placement->invoice,right?

Comment: If you have a 'cars has placements' relationship then yes

Comment: Only one car can be assigned to a placement and a placement can only have one car, but a car can be assigned to more placements if the date is different.
I'm pretty tangled right now...

Comment: It sounds like one car has many 'placement dates' but a 'placement date' only has one placement

Comment: Yes, but on a date can be more placements with different cars.
I mean, you can rent the car with id 1 on 13.10.2018 and the car with id 2 on 13.10.2018

Comment: yep that should be fine

Comment: So...how should i make the relationship? :-?